# Include and Exclude regexp for mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect the access to one of my url's through mod-rewrite, only if the request does not has my site as a referrer, but I want to exclude a specific url with parameters.

This is my rule today (which works for redirecting):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*profile/login*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://example.com(/)?.*$      [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=307,L]
</ifModule>
```

But I want the following url not to be redirected:

https://example.com/profile/login/?my_param=my-param-value&key=XXXXXXX

I do not know before hand the query string values, just the query string names.

How can I exclude those URL of the rule ?

Thank you,

Regards,

GV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the following condition in my .htaccess file to exclude URLs having a particular query string parameter and value.

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)rcp_action=lostpassword_reset($|&)

Considering your rewrite rules, I'd add a new line to check the %{QUERY_STRING} condition as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*profile/login*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://example.com(/)?.*$      [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)rcp_action=lostpassword_reset($|&)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/ [R=307,L]
</ifModule>
```

In your case, you'd need to replace `rcp_action` by your parameter name `my_param`, as well as `lostpassword_reset` by your parameter value, `my-param-value`.

I've tested this in my own site [SlideModel](https://slidemodel.com/), to redirect users to a maintenance page given certain conditions based on the query string parameters.